# Align table cell to center

Tags: html, css, html-table

Below is the code of my table. I want to align the last cell (logout) to the center of table. It aligns to the left and I want it to be center-aligned.

```
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="viewjobseeker.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Edu.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></a>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="viewemployer.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Profile.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></a>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="viewjob.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\jobopening.jpg" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></a>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3"><div align="center"><a href="viewjobseeker.php"><strong>View JobSeeker Profile</strong></a></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3"><div align="center"><a href="viewemployer.php"><strong>View Employer Porfile</strong></a></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3"><div align="center"><a href="viewjob.php"><strong>View Job Opening</strong></a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="editjobseekeradmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\edit.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></a>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="editemployeradmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\editemployer.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></a>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="checkfeedbackadmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Feedback.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></a>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3"><div align="center"><a href="editjobseekeradmin.php"><strong>Edit JobSeeker Profile</strong></a></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3"><div align="center"><a href="editemployeradmin.php"><strong>Edit Employer Profile</strong></a></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3"><div align="center"><a href="checkfeedbackadmin.php"><strong>Check feedback</strong></a></div></td>

  </tr><div id="center1">
  <tr align="center">
   <center>
  <td align="center"><div align="center"><a href="logoutadmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Log.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></div></td></tr></a>
  <tr align="center">    
   <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3" align="center"><div align="center"><a href="logoutadmin.php"><strong>Logout</strong></a></div></td>
     </tr></div></center>
</table>
```

This is the table screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You have a whole heap of syntax errors in your code. It would be a good idea to run your code through [a html validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and come back when you have fixed all of the errors.

Comment: By the way, you should definitely avoid using tables for formatting menus. Instead, use `div`s and set colors, formatting etc via css, as any good HTML tutorial should tell you.

Comment: please check the screenshot i just shared. the logout should come in middle.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_table_align.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/e3j4oacj/1/), is that what you meant?

What I did was to clean all the unneeded divs and add a empty `td` on each side of the full `td` in the last two rows.

```
    <tr align="center">
    <td></td>
    <td text-align="center">
        <div align="center">
            <a href="logoutadmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Log.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /> </a></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
    <td></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A0B9F3" align="center">
        <div align="center"><a href="logoutadmin.php"><strong>Logout</strong></a></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please check the screenshot i just shared.  the logout should come in middle.

Comment: The logout is in the center of the last row, did you wanted something else? have you checked my fiddle?   https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/e3j4oacj/1/

Comment: yea i tried your code...the logout comes in middle but the borders of both left and right  are seen now.what should i do?

Comment: You want borders as in the print screen you uploaded?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/UKlrT  now its coming like this .There are borders on left and right .How to remove them

Comment: Check this link, Is that what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/e3j4oacj/2/

Answer (score 0):

use the below code :
HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div><a href="viewjobseeker.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Edu.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="viewemployer.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Profile.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="viewjob.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\jobopening.jpg" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div><a href="viewjobseeker.php"><strong>View JobSeeker Profile</strong></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="viewemployer.php"><strong>View Employer Porfile</strong></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="viewjob.php"><strong>View Job Opening</strong></a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div><a href="editjobseekeradmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\edit.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="editemployeradmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\editemployer.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="checkfeedbackadmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Feedback.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" /></a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div><a href="editjobseekeradmin.php"><strong>Edit JobSeeker Profile</strong></a></td>
        <td><div><a href="editemployeradmin.php"><strong>Edit Employer Profile</strong></a></div></td>
        <td><div><a href="checkfeedbackadmin.php"><strong>Check feedback</strong></a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div><a href="logoutadmin.php"><img src="\Proj main\images\Log.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" ></a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div><a href="logoutadmin.php"><strong>Logout</strong></a></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
table {
width:50%;
}
table, table td {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table div{
text-align:center;
}
table td{
background:#A0B9F3;
}
```